# IE issue in Selenium: new window is opening instead of new tab

Tags: selenium

When a link is clicked manually in my application, it opens in new tab in Chrome and IE.However when my script is run, the link opens in a new window in IE instead of new tab. Same script runs as expected in Chrome.
Has anyone faced this issue?

Answer (score 0):

When a link is clicked, I understand your test script has code to just do 
element.click()
which opens the link in new tab.

If yes, its upto the app code to open in a new tab or new window. and if it is working in Chrome and not in IE, its nothing to do with your Selenium Test script.

You got to check with your developer to troubleshoot it. I hope it answers your query.